# load image into page curl activity

Tags: android, image

i have loaded a set of images into my sd card and i would like to display them in my page curl activity.

i checked if the images are properly downloaded:

```
 ArrayList<String>  mStringList= new ArrayList<String>();
 File strPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures");
 int lists = strPath.listFiles().length; 
 Log.d("number of items in array ",String.valueOf(lists));

 File yourDir = new File(strPath, "");
 for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
     if (f.isFile())
     {
         String name = f.getName();
         String v = strPath + "/" + name;
         mStringList.add(v);
     }
 }
```

this is the bit map provider:

```
 * Bitmap provider.
 */
private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

    // Bitmap resources.
    private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.drawable.obama, R.drawable.road_rage,
            R.drawable.taipei_101, R.drawable.world };

    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);

        int margin = 7;
        int border = 3;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }

        r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
        r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
        r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
        r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
        c.drawRect(r, p);
        r.left += border;
        r.right -= border;
        r.top += border;
        r.bottom -= border;

        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);

        return b;
    }
```

how do i replace

```
// Bitmap resources.
        private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.drawable.obama, R.drawable.road_rage,
                R.drawable.taipei_101, R.drawable.world }; 
and Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);
```

into those in my sd card?

Comment: @njzk2 I managed to add the items from my sd card into a String[] array but i do not know how to display it into drawable d. that's what i've tried

Comment: i don't understand you comment. you probably have tried to start by figuring how to enumerate images on the sdcard ?

Comment: @njzk2 I meant, I have added the images from my sd card into a String[] mBitmapIds array but now I am having difficulty to display it.

Comment: "difficulty" doesn't mean much in this context. i guess you didn't find BitmapFactory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert an image from sdcard to drawable as:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mStringList[index], options);

Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);;
```

Comment: It says "cannot cast from bitmap to bitmapdrawable". what does that error mean?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If I want to set an image from a web url then how can i do this in the above case.